# Creating a list that contains sets of numbers from two different vectors

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, vector

I have two vectors of numbers:

```
vector_a = (5,10,15,20,25)
vector_b = (6,11,16,21,26)
```

And I want to have a list that gathers the information in this way:

```
[[5,6], [10,11], [15,16], [20,21], [25,26]]
```

Can anyone give me a clue of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use zip.

```
new = [list(x) for x in zip(vector_a,vector_b)]
```

output

```
[[5, 6], [10, 11], [15, 16], [20, 21], [25, 26]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the `zip` function in the `list` function will do just that:

```
list(zip(list_a, list_b))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works although the output is a list of vectors [(5, 6), (10, 11), (15, 16)]

Comment: The output is a list of *tuples*, which (broadly speaking) is (arguably) a lighter data structure than lists. Granted, the specific use-case will dictate if this approach meets the requirement.  Python does not have a ‘vector’ data type.